# vertical center using javascript and css goes wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write a CSS and JavaScript to center divs inside the class `viralign` vertically.

```
<div id="welcome" class="width80 pad5">
    <div class="col-3 vircon">
        <div class="viralign">
            <div>
                image here
            </div>
            <div>
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 vircon">
        <div class="viralign">
            <div>
                image here
            </div>
            <div>
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 vircon">
        <div class="viralign">
            <div>
                image here
            </div>
            <div>
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css clases**

```
.width80{
    width:80%;
    margin:0px auto;}
.pad5{padding:5px;}
.col-3{
    width:33.33%;
}
```

**JavaScript code**

```
function virAlignNavBar(){
    var vircon = document.getElementsByClassName('vircon');
    var viralign = document.getElementsByClassName('viralign');
    for(var i=0; i < vircon.length; i++){
        var x=vircon[i].offsetHeight;
        var y=viralign[i].offsetHeight;
        viralign[i].style.top=((x/2)-(y/2)+"px");
        viralign[i].style.position="absolute";
        vircon[i].style.position="relative";
        }
}
```

The problem is that all divs with class `vircon` appear above each other.
How can I solve this?

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anqy6Lxo/) 
[image]
I need the divs to be like this. the `col-3` class devides the area between the three divs,and the functoin makes the area above each of the three divs equal to the ares below it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add `float="right"` to your function.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anqy6Lxo/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove position absolute and relative.

```js
   function virAlignNavBar(){
     var vircon = document.getElementsByClassName('vircon');
     var viralign = document.getElementsByClassName('viralign');
     for(var i=0; i < vircon.length; i++){
      var x=vircon[i].offsetHeight;
      var y=viralign[i].offsetHeight;
      viralign[i].style.top=((x/2)-(y/2)+"px");
      //viralign[i].style.position="absolute";
      //vircon[i].style.position="relative";
      }
    }
virAlignNavBar();
```

```css
    .width80{
     width:80%;
     margin:0px auto;}
    .pad5{padding:5px;}
    .col-3{
 width:30.33%;
    margin-right:10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="welcome" class="width80 pad5">
 <div class="col-3 vircon">
  <div class="viralign">
   <div>
    image here
   </div>
   <div>
    dfghjk
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-3 vircon">
  <div class="viralign">
   <div>
    image here
   </div>
   <div>
    dfghjk
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-3 vircon">
  <div class="viralign">
   <div>
    image here
   </div>
   <div>
    dfghjk
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Working JSFilddle http://jsfiddle.net/anqy6Lxo/3/

Comment: It's not working. There is no vertical align to center, and divs now are not next to each other anymore.You can't set top without using absolute position.

Comment: Thats not What I want. I want to center divs that are inside the class `viralign` verticaly.

Comment: @YazanWYusuf What do you mean by center? Those two divs inside class viralign are already centered. What functionality you are looking for? Can you be more clear?

Comment: Give us a picture what you're looking for please. It's not obvious.

Comment: @DivakarDass I attached a picture and I hope it will make the question more clear.

Comment: @kashesandr I attached a picture and I hope it will make the question more clear.